# Android Actvities problem for getting result

Tags: android

I have two activities A & b.

in A i have one button which takes me to the activity B. in Activity B i have one edit text. when user enter some values in edittext i m getting the value in some variable. and i want to pass this value back to activity A. i applied the Bundle concept bt it is force closing my app.

pls anybody can help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's force-closing, what does the stacktrace say?

Answer (score 0):

you should use Intent.putExtra() to transfer the value.

Comment: in activity B m doing the same Intent.putExtra(). but i have to get the value by get string in A. here it is crashing.